# How to count the number of times an element appered in entire dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'names_1' : ['cat', 'dog', 'elephant'],
              'names_2' : ['rat', 'cat', 'tiger'],
              'names_3' : ['cow', 'monkey', 'cat']})


# Output -

    names_1     names_2    names_3
0   cat         rat        cow
1   dog         cat        monkey
2   elephant    tiger      cat
```

I want to count the number of time `'cat'` appeared in the entire dataset. I know about `value_counts()` method, but it only counts the element in a specific column. How do I count `cat` appearance in the entire dataset?

**Edit** - In my use case, I want to return a dictionary of counts of each element, like this:

```
{cat:3, dog:1, elephant:1, etc..}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names_1' : ['cat', 'dog', 'elephant'],
                  'names_2' : ['rat', 'cat', 'tiger'],
                  'names_3' : ['cow', 'monkey', 'cat']})
    
occurence = df.stack().value_counts().to_dict()
```

results in

```
{'cat': 3, 'rat': 1, 'cow': 1, 'dog': 1, 'monkey': 1, 'elephant': 1, 'tiger': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) on the flatten underlying numpy array. This is ~2–100 times faster than using `value_counts` depending on the size of the dataframe.

```
from collections import Counter
dict(Counter(df.values.ravel().tolist()))
```

output:

```
{'cat': 3,
 'rat': 1,
 'cow': 1,
 'dog': 1,
 'monkey': 1,
 'elephant': 1,
 'tiger': 1}
```